# Loop through Listviews and their items

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have 3 Listviews and I'm changing backcolor of particular items in them. Now I want to change all item backcolor in all Listviews. How could I do this ?

This doesn't work (code gets skipped):

```
For Each Ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
 If (TypeOf Ctrl Is System.Windows.Forms.ListView) Then
     Dim currentListView As System.Windows.Forms.ListView = DirectCast(Ctrl, System.Windows.Forms.ListView)
        For Each item In currentListView.Items
                 item.backcolor = SystemColors.Window
        Next
 End If
Next
```

EDIT:

```
Dim test = New System.Windows.Forms.ListView() {ListView1, ListView2, ListView3}
For Each item In test
    item.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
Next
```

Comment: "This doesn't work" is not an accurate description of a problem. What do you mean by "Code gets skipped"?

Comment: @Jens, when I set break point at "For each Ctrl...." and hit F11, all code gets skipped after If statement- so It doesn't enter "Dim currentListview...".

Comment: If you have 3 listviews, put them in an array and loop thru *that*.  If the LVs are in containers they wont be in Me.Controls.  Plus you wont have to cast

Comment: What Plutonix said. If you want to keep it as general, you would have to iterate over all subcontainers recursively.

Comment: @Plutonix, yes they are in containers. But how to loop items with array, I can't get It to work - see my edited question.

Comment: In that loop, item would be a LV - the previous form of the code (and the text question) was looping thru *the items* in each LV.

Comment: @Plutonix, I'm not sure if I follow you now. You say I have to combine both codes together to get desired result ?

Comment: Please give an example of the "particular items" you want to change - is it by name, a subitem value?

Comment: @Plutonix, nevermind, I got It working using arrays as you suggested. I just needed to do little differently as in my question. I will post an answer now. Thanks for that, quite frustrating issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. If Listviews are in containers you need to put them in array and do loop like this:

```
Dim LVies = New System.Windows.Forms.ListView() {ListView1, ListView2, Listview3}

    For Each LV In LVies
        For Each item As ListViewItem In LV.Items
                 item.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        Next
    Next
```